# printing the x coordinate from a set of points in a list in python

Tags: python

I just started python, I want to print the x coordinates from a list of an array containing points(x,y). Need something like this.

```
 def printXCoord(array):
                for i, element in enumerate(array):
                    print(array[i].x)
```

This should print all the x coordinates from a list of points(x,y)

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: How given array look like can you example???

Comment: it looks like this array = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (3, 2), (6, 2), (8, 1), (8, 9), (7, 7), (1, 5)]
i want the code to print 1, 3, 4, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 1

Answer (score 0):

if the array contains a list of `(x, y)`, then your code would be

```py
def printXCoord(array):
    for _, element in enumerate(array):
        #element looks like (x, y), so element[0] is the x value
        print(element[0])
```